# How do I print a Thunderbird contact name and address on an postal envelope?

Tags: printing, libreoffice, thunderbird, contacts

I want to select a Thunderbird contact and print the name and address directly on to a postal envelope for mailing.

I do not want to print a list of contacts or fiddle around with single labels. Yes, I can handwrite the details on the envelope but it is not ideal. I have tried LibreOffice>Writer>Envelope but it results in all contacts being included in the output document. Ditto for mail merge.

Lubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

LibreOffice Version: 4.2.7.2 Build ID: 420m0(Build:2)

Thunderbird 31.5.0

This should be such an obvious and simple thing.  Please help.

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1008958

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I tried that.  For one thing, it does not single out a specific record for printing and secondly, it prints to labels not on to an envelope.  My question was specific on both points.

Comment: So you tried using (Open Office instead of LibreOffice) as specified in the solution I linked? Please [edit] your question to include that fact if so. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I tried the equivalent on LibreOffice. For one thing, it does not single out a specific record for printing and secondly, it prints to labels not on to an envelope. My question was specific on both points. The original question and the specification is for LibreOffice.

Comment: You may wish to follow your question here: http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/48726/how-do-i-print-a-thunderbird-contact-name-and-address-on-an-postal-envelope/ or considering your narrow specificatons, http://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/professional-support/

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I put addresses on my letters and use window envelopes but perhaps this will be more to your liking.

**From the writer menu select File->Insert->Envelope.**

You'll see something like this:

[image: letter1a]

Here you'll choose your registered database details for pulling your contact info in. (For more on registering a database see Help, address books;registering)or check the documentation [here](http://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/documentation/) or perhaps [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Address_Data_Source)

**Change to the Format tab** displaying this:

[image: letter1b]

and adjust to match your envelope.

Finally, move to the Printer tab and choose the orientation at which you will feeding your envelope as below, adjusting any other settings as necessary to your requirements:

[image: letter1c]

Now, **Click the New Document Button.** You'll see something similar to this:

[image: letterfinal]

Make final adjustments/corrections so that everything aligns the way you want, insert your envelope in the printer based on the orientation chosen previously and click print.

If anything doesn't work as advertised, bugs can be reviewed and reported here: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org//

Comment: Thank you.  How do I get a record selected in Thunderbird to appear in the Addressee field of the Envelope form?  I'd settle for copy/pasting the address from TB to the LO form.  It is the selection of usable record data that is the heart of this.

Comment: @ Elder Greek. It is possible in TB to select (right mouse click) a contact, select Print Preview, select Print..., Print to File, Open the saved file, copy the name and postal address then paste into the LO Envelope form addressee field - but this is not a great solution.  I was rather hoping that someone might know of an add-in that does the task?

Comment: Based on the Documentation, that's supposed to be baked in. If it's not working, It might be helpful to report it as a bug.

Comment: Which application's documentation please?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear - LibreOffice documentation.

Comment: @ Elder Greek. Thank you for your help with this.  I've tried it every which way and there is no simple, slick solution to this.  So I have developed an answer of my own using a free software called gLabels (available from Ubuntu Software Centre) and LO Base .  Working a feasible solution took some time - hence the delay in my response. I will post the details in a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

### ***OVERVIEW***

An additional software application is needed to print a selected Thunderbird (TB) contact to an envelope using LibreOffice (LO).  That software is gLabels and it is available from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

This method requires a fair amount of non-technical effort to set up.  Once the templates are there, printing direct to envelopes is easy.

### ***BEFORE YOU START YOU WILL NEED...***

1. LO Base (the database module) installed.
2. gLabels installed from Ubuntu Software Centre

### ***GIVE LIBREOFFICE ACCESS TO THUNDERBIRD CONTACT DATABASE***

3. In LO Writer select File>Wizard>Address Data Source> Thunderbird/Icedove>[Contact table name]. This creates a data connection between TB contacts and LO. Name the .odb file.

### ***CREATE A LIBREOFFICE DATABASE FILE TO PROCESS THUNDERBIRD CONTACT DATA***

4. Open LO Base>Open an existing database file>navigate to your saved .odb file>Finish
5. Select Queries>Use Wizard to Create Query>Select the table storing your contact data and pick the fields holding the salutations, names and address data.  Complete Wizard to create query.
6. Right mouse click on the query and select Edit.  Change the order of fields and sort/filter the data as required.
   **TOP TIP** Have the first field/column containing concatenated first and family names (in TB Contacts this is called 'Display').  This will be used as a record identifier in gLabels.
7. Save the .odb database

### ***EXPORT THE REQUIRED DATA TO A CSV FILE THAT CAN BE READ BY gLabels***

8. Right click on the Base query and select [Copy]
9. Select File>New>Spreadsheet to open a new LO Calc file
10. Right Mouse click in cell A1 and select [Paste]
11. Save the Calc file as **CSV** in a location you will remember.  This is the CSV that will be used by gLabels.

### ***CREATE ENVELOPE TEMPLATE FILES IN gLabels***

12. Open gLabels.  Select File>Template Designer
13. Follow the Wizard using the page size to define the size of the envelope.
14. Use the dimensions width and height from the Page size tab to define the label dimensions on the 'Label or Card Size' tab.  You only want 1 label - about envelope sized!  This can be confirmed in the Layout(s) tab.
15. When your envelope template is completed click File>New>Custom and follow the wizard.  You have an orientation option at this point - select 'Rotated'.
16. Open the envelope template you have created.
17. Select Objects>Merge properties> Format: Text:Comma Separated Values (CSV). Location: - Navigate to the **CSV** saved in step 11. You'll be able to check all is OK because you will see data listed from the first field in the preview pane.
18. Unselect All> then tick the record corresponding to the contact you want to address on the envelope.  Clicking the left triangle next to the contact data will expand the record vertically showing **field numbers** and the data held therein. You will need to refer to this later.
19. Save the Envelope Template.  You can create a shortcut to this on your desktop for convenience.
20. Click the 'Create Text Object' and click/drag to create a text rectangle aligned to the top left corner of the envelope area. Select the Text tab in the right pane and click the Insert merge field button. A pick list allows you to select the fields you need for the envelope using the **field numbers** mentioned in step 18.  These fields can be arranged on the same line with spaces or placed on new lines by editing the text in the right pane window.
21. Save your file.  Check your work with a print preview as follows (and edit if required)
22. Click Edit Merge Properties icon to see a list of contacts. Unselect All> then Tick the record corresponding to the contact you want to address on the envelope. Click OK.
23. Select File>Print...>Preview to see how the envelope will print.
24. Fine tune the layout by editing the gLabels template file. Save the file.

### ***HAPPY PRINTING***

25. To print your envelope, open the gLabels template and perform steps 22 & 23.

*CHECK YOUR ADDRESS BEFORE PRINTING! YOU ARE NOT ACCESSING THUNDERBIRD DATA DIRECTLY. BE PREPARED TO REPEAT STEPS 8-11 TO REFRESH THE LABEL DATA FILE.*

### ***ADDITIONAL NOTES***

This method does not link to TB contact data dynamically but refers to a snapshot CSV intermediate file which means that the more regularly names and addresses are changed, the more frequently the CSV needs to be rebuilt (steps 8-11)

If anyone can refine this method to get closer to dynamic data processing - eg. a shell script to create a fresh the CSV before opening the gLabels envelope template file, that would be great.

If someone could write an add-in for Thunderbird or LibreOffice that did all this in a simple way, that would be superb!